# Remove Logcat from Java Perspective

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, eclipse-adt

How can I remove the logcat window from the Java perspective permanently? Every time I get an error (that I'm expecting) it pops up the logcat window (even if i close it/remove it from the perspective) and shows the output. I only want this showing in the debug perspective. It's very annoying and makes iterative testing difficult when trying to fix known issues. I really don't need eclipse changing my focus to an error I've already seen a few dozen times.

I've tried going to "customize perspective" but I can only see options to add it, and even though it's not checked (and presumably not added) it still pops up.

Comment: +1 for asking the same question I was about to ask.

Answer (score 26):

Turn it off in *Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Logcat -> Display logcat view when there are messages from an application in the workspace.*

Comment: The option `Display logcat view when there are messages from an application in the workspace` doesn't seem to exist.....

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent Eclipse from automatically opening views like that based on which perspective you're in via your preferences, check the settings seen in the image below:

[image: Eclipse view management preferences]

Answer (score 0):

I have unchecked `Monitor logcat for messages from applications in workspace` instead of `Display logcat view when there are messages from an application in the workspace`

SDK version: 20.

Comment: This doesn't work because the messages don't appear **at all**.